# Current navigation step

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs

Is there a easy way to get current navigation step inside casper script (like in debug output: "Step xx/yy done in ZZZms"). Or only way is count steps by myself?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, CasperJS doesn't keep track of step execution time or current step index. You either do it yourself or monkey-patch the `casper` instance. If you decide to do it yourself

- you can time the step in question from the surrounding steps or
- use [`step.start`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#step-start), [`step.complete`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#step-complete), [`step.error`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#step-error) and [`step.timeout`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#step-timeout) events. This will not work correctly, because `step.complete` is not emitted for `casper.start` or `casper.thenOpen`, but `step.start` is.